# Routing Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've trying to make routing work on Backbone but its quite cryptic to me at this point. This is what I have

```
    routes: {
        ''            : 'home',
        'home'        : 'home',
        'departments' : 'departments',
        'employees'   : 'employees',
        'requests'    : 'requests'
    },

    home: function(){
        new app.HomeView();
    },
```

This is inside my router and obviously I call Backbone.history.start(). On my view I have the pattern to define a render function and call it from the initialize method.

```
    el: '#containerList',

    template: Handlebars.compile( $('#home-template').html() ),

    initialize: function(){         
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template());
        return this;
    },
```

HTML:

```
<section id='main' class='container'>
  <section id='containerList'></section>
</section>
```

I have the following issues:

1. On back button, views get appended. I need to reload the page to fix this.
2. Whenever writing the route on the browser search bar I need to reload it twice to get the view to show. It has a very unstable behavior, sometimes it renders the views without the collections.

I've read many strategies, to use event on CloseView, use this.remove on leaving the view. Apparently nothing of this works for me. I see little documentation of routers on backbone.

Comment: Since you're replacing the entire html like `this.$el.html( this.template());` it's very unlikely that something will get appended... can you create a [mcve]..?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing a function that will add and remove the main view of the current route. So you router will look like:

```
routes: {
        ''            : 'home',
        'home'        : 'home',
        'departments' : 'departments',
        'employees'   : 'employees',
        'requests'    : 'requests'
    },

    home: function(){
        var view = new app.HomeView();
        this.setMainView(view);      
    },

    setMainView: function(view) {
            this.mainView && this.mainView.remove();
            this.mainView = view;
            this.mainView.setElement($('#main'));
   }
```

And then you don't need to predefine the el of the view so your view will look like this:

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile( $('#home-template').html() ),

    initialize: function(){         
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template());
        return this;
    }
```

})

Basically you have a div element that contain the current main view (#main) and on every route function you need to call the setMainView function to set the current view.